# Help center privileges established user page seems to have a markdown error

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

[Help Center > Privileges > Established User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user).

The page currently looks like this.
[image]

The first line seems to have a markdown error. It currently says

`###What are Established Users?`

But I surmise that it should be a header, and that there is just a space missing between the hashtags and the text.

It should be

`### What are the Established Users?`

Comment: They probably missed we moved to [Common Mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) *Headlines: Moving forward, you have to add a space after the leading # characters.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed! Thanks for pointing this out.