# Markdown error in "Why have I been limited to one question per week?" help center page

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, help-center

The help center page [Why have I been limited to one question per week?](//stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited) has a Markdown error. There isn't any space in-between the three hash symbols (###) and the text, resulting in the following:

> ###Why am I being told that I can only ask one question per week?

I assume the intended result is:

> #### Why am I being told that I can only ask one question per week?

This seems to have [happened before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/428022/20153035), and was likely caused by the [move to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/1416577).

Here's a quick screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing bad markdown]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the page again, I see the issue has been fixed:

[image: Screenshot]